# Taking input inside a recursive function (one time input on the first iteration) in c++

Tags: c++, function, recursion

Until now, for me the only way to retain a particular variable value inside of a recursive function is to pass it as a parameter. But this time i am specifically required to write a function which takes only two integers as parameters, and takes a string input on the first iteration.

Pseudo code:

> function (int a, int b)
>
> ```
> if a == 1 and b == 2 take a string as input
>
> else // do something with that string and print it
> ```

The code i came up with:

```
void f(int a, int b)
{
    string s;
    if (a == 1 and b == 2)
    {
        cin >> s;
    }
    //do something with a, b and string
    //some recursive calls based on conditions
    /* for example */ 
    if (!(a == 3 and b == 6))
    {
        f(a + 1, b + 2);
    }
    cout << s << "\n";
}

//and then call this function in the main function as f(1, 2);
```

I get what's wrong with my code, but i don't understand how to resolve it. Is there a way to take input inside the recursive function and print it's value in another recursive call?

Comment: Cheat: If you need to do something on the first-and-only-the-first recursion, insert another function to handle that first case. In your case `f` asks for the string, does the first step of the job, and then calls `f_inner` which calls itself. If you can eliminate the bit of code duplication with yet another small function called by `f` and `f_inner`, do it.

Comment: I don't understand the question. It looks to me like that the example code answers the question.

Comment: Have you already been told what `static` means?

Comment: @user4581301 I think i understand what you are trying to say, i am gonna give it a try.

Comment: @Bob__ As simple as that lol. I have become a little rusty on c++. Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: @user4581301 , the issue is resolved but yours seems like a valuable advice. I am gonna keep that in mind. Thank you

Comment: Be careful with "do something with a, b and string some recursive calls based on conditions", always remember to put a termination condition. Also, if it's solved, consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to use a "static" variable instead of a local variable. According to the specific instructions given, it was not possible to declare a variable globally outside of the function and the parameters were fixed. By simply declaring the string variable as static, it is possible to make it retain it's value between successive calls.

so just change `string s;` to `static string s;`

Comment: @Bob__ yeah that is more precise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable s as a global variable. You can't access s outside the call as its scope gets destroyed as soon as the function ends.

Comment: that's the problem, the variable cannot be declared before hand, it has to be in the function itself.